# Вывести слоган, текст которого не помещается полностью

Tags: drupal

мне надо вывести слоган в drupal 6, но текст не помешается в него полностью,
вопросы-как увеличить длину поля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
* Increase the length of the slogan.
* Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter.
*/
function MODULENAME_form_system_site_information_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['site_information']['site_slogan']['#maxlength'] = 255; // limit of characters
}
```

https://drupal.org/node/1014468

Comment: куда этот код вписать?

Comment: http://azbukaweb.ru/creating-modules-a-tutorial-drupal-7x